# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/TableRow

Tags: java, apache, maven

I have a problem when I'm trying to run my maven project. It compiles just fine but when I run it I'm taking this error message :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/TableRow
```

Comment: You're missing your dependency for TableRow or else it's not on the class path for the project.. check your build path configuration

Comment: @AK47 Thank you very much. I was missing the TableRow dependency just like you said